# How to refer to other html page using enter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, enter

I made a form. And I want it to go to another html page when I fill in the form and hit enter (value of the field filled doesn't matter). How would I do that with javascript? this is my form:

```
           <form class="zoek-enter" >
              <div class="form-control">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Zoeken...">
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by going to another html page?

Presuming you mean that you would want to submit the form, you could add a form action attribute to the form tag, with the relevant HTTP method.

```html
<form action="/another_page" method="post">
  <!-- your inputs here -->
</form>
```

**But** if you were to mean that you just want to be redirected to another webpage by pressing `Enter` key..

```
<form class="zoek-enter" >
    <div class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Zoeken..." onkeypress="redirect(event)">
</div>
```

```js
function redirect(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    window.location.replace("www.your-webpage-here.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i ment rederecting to another web page, sry for the confusing! But it works now so thank you :) i tried the same thing but i guess something went wrong with the names or so. Im a beginner but im still learning everyday :)